# The existence of integral equations solution for a 2-dimensional unknown function

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Suppose $f(\cdot,\cdot)\in C[0,1]^2$ is a kernel. $f$ is integratble $\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)dxdy<\infty$.

$a,b\in C[0,1]$ are known functions, and $z(\cdot,\cdot)\in C[0,1]^2$ is a 2-dimensional unkown function such that

$\int_0^1 z(x,y)f(y,x)dy=a(x)$, $\forall x$ and

$\int_0^1 z(x,y)f(x,y)dx=b(y)$, $\forall y$

The question is there is any results that such system has a solution for $z(\cdot,\cdot)$?

Thanks.